# How to Lasso-select multiple files in Nautilus using the mouse in List-View? 

Tags: nautilus, mouse

Is there some way that Nautilus can be made to select multiple files as a Rectangle-select action of the mouse (Lassoo style) in the  list view? Compact and Icons view work ok.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can already do that in Nautilus with the default configuration. Or I may have misunderstand something.

Comment: Thanks.. that probably means I have changed something unknowingly.. I'll test it na a VM

Comment: @Nayamiou: This issue only applies to **List View**.. I never use any other view...  (but, yes, it does work in Icon and Compact view)... I'll add this bit of extra information into my question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible because of the nature of this view.

However: to select multiple files I suggest you learn the <kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard shortcut for selecting files "in a row" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for selecting individual files "all over the place" as it were. You'll quickly pick these up.

Comment: . Thanks. Maybe it is not "fixable" but it is a bit of a surprise, seeing it can do it in the other two views.. but perhaps it is because there is no **neutral ground** where the first click can start from without effecting the dran-n-drop....  Actually, I haven't noticed it until today, because I'm an avid "prefer-the-keyboard" user, but this is one of the few places I actually like to **experience** the mouse... Ah.. c'est la vie..  I'll hold off a bit for now, somoene may pull a rabbit out of the hat.. :)   (the mouse is good for scrolling, no doubt about that)

Comment: "I don't think this is possible because of the nature of this view.", just want to point out that `Dolphin` is more than capable of doing this in its own _List_ (_Detailed_) view.

Answer (score 4):

See this upstream [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138931).

Comment: Okay.. That's intersting... it is the Drag-n-Drop... I **almost** never use DnD, and when I do it is usually accidently... I wonder if it is possible to **turn off DnD** ?.. preferably only for Nautilus... (Lasoo-selection may still not work, but it may)

Answer (score 1):

This is a highly commented bug (see bug report link from htorque above) for which it appears a Nautilus developer is active in.

However it seems it is not a bug that is likely to be resolved anytime soon, this is a dissapointing shock that the Gnome file manager is crippled in what seems a basic function!

**There appears to be a [preliminary Patch fix](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=120435&action=edit)**

but I have no idea how to use it!

It is a shame that such a condesending response has been given (above by fluteflute) when clearly there is a genuine issue with Nautilus, I guess using Thunar is another possible alternitive as lassoo selection in List View in Thunar (and probably other File managers too)